# How to use DevExpress GridView button to implement 2 functions?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am using DevExpress GridView to show data on the webpage.

I would like to show 2 different data with only one button.

For example, the button displays the button name "List data A",
when I click it, data A will show on the webpage
and at the same time the button name will change to "List data B"
when I click the button again, data B will show on the webpage
and the button name will change back to "List data A" .

Below is the javascript of the button:

```
<div id="text3"><input name="preview6" type="button" class="btn9" id="preview6" onclick="MM_showHideLayers('table_A','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('table_B','','show');MM_showHideLayers('text3','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('text3_after','','show')" value="List data A" /></div>
<div id="text3_after"><input name="preview6" type="button" class="btn9" id="preview6" onclick="MM_showHideLayers('table_B','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('table_A','','show');MM_showHideLayers('text3_after','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('text3','','show')" value="List data B" /></div>
```

Is it possible to implement the function above by using dx:ASPxButton ?
Please advise and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In the Click event of ASPXButton, capture the text of the button.

```
    if (button.Text == "List A")
    {
         //do something here
         button.Text = "List B";
    }
    else if (button.Text == "List B")
    {
         //do something here
         button.Text = "List A";
    }
```

If you will use javascript, then maybe you can do the checking and changing of Text button there. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I found another solution to do it. I am using ASPxCallbackPanel method to implement this function.